# How can I return a database query and redirect at once?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I don't literally need to use "res.redirect()", I just mean I want to take the user to a different page using any workable method.

After the user enters their info, they click a button which calls createUser.  createUser successfully adds a new entry to the database.  I want the user to also be automatically redirected back to the index page ("/").  I have not found any way to do this.  What I have below does hit "app.get('/'), but no redirect happens.  Is it possible to put the redirect in app.post('/api/register-new-user')?  Can I use window.location somehow within createUser?  I have tried both of those ways to no avail.

```
// CLIENT =====
$scope.createUser = function() {
    $http.post('/api/register-new-user', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
            $scope.users = data;
            console.log(data);
//  window.location = "./";
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    $http.get('/')
    .success(function(data) {
    })
    .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};

//SERVER========
app.post('/api/register-new-user', function(req, res) {
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
if(err)
    res.send(err);
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash){
    if(err)
    res.send(err);
    User.create({
    username : req.body.username,
    password : hash
    }, function(err, user) {
    if(err)
        res.send(err)
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
    });
    });
});
});

});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    console.log('register');
    res.sendfile('./public/views/register.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are doing your browser/server interaction to create a user via AJAX and HTTP redirects over AJAX have no bearing on the URL/page loaded in the browser. So you can forget about server side HTTP redirects. Just send a 201 status to be nicely RESTful and call it good on the server.

On the client, if the POST succeeds you can just trigger a new route with `$location.path('/');`. Just make sure you declare `$location` so it gets injected by DI into your controller.

Also note that the active user probably needs to be set on the `$rootScope` if you want it to be broadly available to the rest of your controllers.

Comment: I'm new to MEAN.  Could you please explain your last paragraph?

Comment: Second question, where does $location come from?  Should that just exist within the angular controller?  I get $location not defined.

Comment: $location needs to go in your controller function which you omitted in your snippet. Above your snippet where you have something like `function ($scope, $http) {...` add `$location` as a function argument there and angular will inject it.

Comment: But this will only change the URL, not take the user to a new page, right?  Right now it just appends '#/' to the end of the url.

Comment: If your app only uses 1 controller so far, you're fine storing the user data there. But eventually your app will have several controllers and you'll move from the signUpController to the homePageController and those 2 don't share any data so the user will disappear. If you want to share it, move it up to the $rootScope.

Comment: You probably want to use angular's html5Mode which won't have the `#` in the URL. Check the tutorials on how to configure that in the $locationProvider.

Comment: But will that do the redirect then?  Also, am I going about this in the right way in general?  This seems like something that should flow more  since I imagine almost every page will do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67942/discussion-between-peter-lyons-and-michaeladam).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
window.location.href()
```

Instead of window.location().

This should work with an absolute path.

Although as you are using Angular so it is possible to use the route provider to update the view with out redirecting the user.

Here is some documentation for the route provider.
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07